# Refactorisation of an if Block

Tags: c#, if-statement, conditional-statements, refactoring

In the following code I have 2 `if` block.
A, The first return the error when the object is null.
B, the second will try to send the object and if it' fails then return and error. It should be executed only if not A, the object is not null.

```
private bool SendToERP(Foo foo, out string error)
{
    error = "";
    var ticketIn = TicketFromFoo(foo, out string err);

    if(ticketIn == null)
    {
        error = err;
        return false;
    }

    if ( !GenericERP_TicketSubmit(ticketIn, out err))
    {
        error = err;
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

The action after those condition are the same and I want to refactor on into a unique `if` block.

As I can't warp my head 2 condition and an `and` I wrote a [simple truth table](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uESNYk) to help me. But it didn't help me mutch.

Comment: I know it's trivial But Im missing one step and I don't know where.

Comment: So you want to perform some action if one condition is true OR the other?

Comment: Well I suposse I got lost between null/not null and the fact that my b in the Truth table is not true. Or it's friday.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your question you can combine two `IF` as @Thierry V answer

```
if(ticketIn == null || !GenericERP_TicketSubmit(ticketIn, out err))
```

but We can use another angle to read the question. This function expects to return `bool` so we can only write in a statement instead of `IF`.

```
return !(ticketIn == null || !GenericERP_TicketSubmit(ticketIn, out err))
```

We can use another skill ([De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)) let `!` into the statement, that 
will reverse all logic, let the code more clear.

1.`ticketIn == null` will be `ticketIn != null`

2.`||` will be `&&`

3.`!GenericERP_TicketSubmit(ticketIn, out err)` will be `GenericERP_TicketSubmit(ticketIn, out err)`

so we can get

```
return ticketIn != null && GenericERP_TicketSubmit(ticketIn, out err)
```

the code can use like.

```
private bool SendToERP(Foo foo, out string error)
{
    error = "";

    var ticketIn = TicketFromFoo(foo, out error);

    return ticketIn != null && GenericERP_TicketSubmit(ticketIn, out error);
}
```

Comment: I think OP and the quality of your answer would really benefit from an explanation as to why you can remove the IF...

Comment: @xdtTransform my mistake. that was a major overlook. I deleted my comment

Comment: @MongZhu, you were **not** wrong. `createTicketIn ticketIn;
            return (ticketIn = TicketFromRapport(rapport, out error))!= null && GenericAxTicketSubmit(ticketIn, out error);`, But it's not really more readable or anything. I had never saw this syntax, and it's cool to learn.

Comment: @fubo: Yes, the out paramter must be assigned in `SendToERP` but it's also true in `TicketFromFoo` that as an out parameter. So as one call the other, `error = "";` is not needed. At least not on c#7, .net4.5.

Comment: @xdtTransform ,@MongZhu I add some explanation.

Comment: @arekzyla I didn't know the name before, but now I know :),Thanks

Comment: @xdtTransform Ah good to know, thanx for trying it out. And I agree, it is horrible to read. ;)

Answer (score 8):

The `&&` and `||` operators short-circuit. It is considered from left to right. That means:

1) If `&&` evaluates its first operand as false, it does not evaluate its second operand.

2) If `||` evaluates its first operand as true, it does not evaluate its second operand.

In your case, if `ticketIn` is null, you don't want the `TicketSubmit` executed.
So, you can group 2 conditions by an `OR`. Like this.

```
    var ticketIn = TicketFromFoo(foo, out string err);        
    if(ticketIn == null || !GenericERP_TicketSubmit(ticketIn, out err))
    {
         error = err;
         return false;
    }
    return true;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to look up at c# 7 with new Value Tuples. We could also refactor all code on this way:

```
    private (bool result, string error) SendToERP(Foo foo)
    {
        var result = TryMakeTicketFromFoo(foo, out TicketIn ticketIn);
        return result.isSuccess ? GenericERP_TicketSubmit(ticketIn) : result;
    }
```

You need to refactor semantic of your other method also:

```
    private (bool isSuccess, string error) GenericERP_TicketSubmit(TicketIn ticketIn)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private (bool isSuccess, string error) TryMakeTicketFromFoo(Foo foo, out TicketIn ticketIn)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```